# How to know location (x,y) postion of content in web browser window?

Tags: javascript

I have a web view (web window). In JavaScript, we have a function
window.scrollTo(x,y).
So the content will move to (x,y) position. But now I want to do a opposite thing:
Assume that I have an anchor tag. When the content go to that tag. I want to know (x,y) moving position.

Can JavaScript do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically retrieve Html element (X,Y) position with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an offset method which gives you the (x, y) co-ordinates relative to the document - I hope this is what you're after.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Javascript !== jQuery

Answer (score -1):

in python we can do:

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('YOUR PATH') 
print(element.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
```

this will print x and y positions

if you are using java you need search for something like "location_once_scrolled_into_view" in java

Comment: Looks like the question specifically asks about Javascript... what on Earth are you talking about with python and java ???